# How to move multiple objects in a concentric motion?

Tags: animation, modifiers

I have a problem with a little animation. I'm a beginner...

I need to move the red objects forward to his center in a radial way.
I made a circular array and now I need to move each part (i come from 3DS and there is a function for moving only one part and sharing the movements with the others, respecting their normals.

The disc is rotating and all the red parts must move in the arrow direction. But the goal is to move 1 red object in order to move all the others (in some animations I have to move a lot of them, maybe more than 50).

It's not important to connect those movements to the disc, I can make it manually if it's hard to reach. The most important is to avoid spending time because I have to repeat this type of animation in different contexts. They are not final animations but just trials to find the correct way.

I'm looking for quick setup without bones or cinematic.

Comment: are all your small red objects affected by the circular movement?

Comment: yes...the disc is rotating and all the red parts must move in the arrow direction....but the goal is to move 1 red part in order to move all the other (in some animations I have to move a lot of them...maybe more than 50)....is not important to connect those movements to the disc. I can make it manually if it's hard to reach. The most important thing is to avoid time because I have to repeat this type of animation in different contests.
They are not final animations but just trials to reach the correct way

Answer (score 4):

One way is to use vertex based instancing of the moving parts on a dodecagon (12-segment mesh circle). Then animate the scale of the circle.

First set a scale limit constraint on your object:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Fantastic...I will try this method. It seems clean.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand correctly, I think it's the easiest way to do it:

- Parent your object to an empty (or any other object that they are supposed to follow).

[image]

- In the *Pivot Point* panel, enable the *Only Origins* option.

[image]

- Select all your objects and create a keyframe.

[image]

- Move in the timeline, press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, scale down, except that with the *Only Origins* option enabled it will make the objects come closer to each others instead of scaling them. Create a second keyframe.

[image]

- When you're ok don't forget to disable the *Only Origins* option. If you need to move, rotate or scale the empty, the animations will follow without problem.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It's exactly what I was looking for...

Comment: It would be great to find a relatively simple way for the objects to follow the guide-curves as they rotate... unfortunately 'Clamp To' isn't good enough..:(